# Combining two Worksheet Change Events in one Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to combine two worksheet events. Both work individually. I haven't found a way to combine them.

Macro 1: Automatically updating Timestamp Data Entries

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim myTableRange As Range
    Dim myDateTimeRange As Range
    Dim myUpdatedRange As Range
    Set myTableRange = Range("W4:W3000")
    If Intersect(Target, myTableRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set myDateTimeRange = Range("AF" & Target.Row)
    Set myUpdatedRange = Range("AG" & Target.Row)
    If myDateTimeRange.Value = "" Then
        myDateTimeRange.Value = Now
    End If
    myUpdatedRange.Value = Now
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Macro 2: Allowing for multiple selection in Dropdown lists

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xRng As Range
    Dim xValue1 As String
    Dim xValue2 As String
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xRng = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    If xRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, xRng) Is Nothing Then
        xValue2 = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        xValue1 = Target.Value
        Target.Value = xValue2
        If xValue1 <> "" Then
            If xValue2 <> "" Then
                If xValue1 = xValue2 Or _
                    InStr(1, xValue1, "; " & xValue2) Or _
                    InStr(1, xValue1, xValue2 & ";") Then
                    Target.Value = xValue1
                Else
                    Target.Value = xValue1 & "; " & xValue2
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I like to use a `Select` for my `Intersect`, so I can put separate change events for each particular case

Comment: This is pretty straightforward, use an `If` statement to check the first range intersect, then a second `If` statement to check the next (`xlCellTypeAllValidation`). Keep in mind that you maybe could use `If ... Then ... Else If ...`, but both conditions may be true. In that case it's `If ... Then ... End If`  and `If ... Then ... End If`.

Comment: Thank you @Cyril for providing your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a module and add two subs there:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub updateTimestampDataEntries(ByVal c As Range)
'put the code here - using c instead of target
End Sub

Public Sub allowMultipleSelectionDropdown(ByVal c As Range)
'put the code here - using c instead of target
End Sub
```

Then you can use these subs within your worksheet_events like this

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
dim c as Range: set c = Target.Cells(1,1)   'only check the first cell

If Not Application.Intersect(c, rgMyTable) Is Nothing Then
    updateTimestampDataEntries c
ElseIf not Application.Intersect(c, rgValidationLists) Is Nothing Then
    allowMultipleSelectionDropdown c
End If

End Sub

Private Property Get rgMyTable() as Range
'put your code here
set rgMyTable = ...
End Property

Private Property Get rgValidationLists as range
'put your code here
set rgValidationLists = ...
End Property
```

Comment: Hi Ike, 

I'm slightly confused with the setrgMyTable = ... and set rgValidationLists = ...

What should be included there? Do I copy the code from the created module there?

Comment: Use the code from the worksheet event, e.g. `Set rgMyTable = me.Range("W4:W300")`. Always use explicit references with Range - you avoid trouble.

Comment: Hi @Ike, many thanks for the help!
The solution works and no issues are experienced.